# How to configure Atom Beautify?

Tags: emacs, atom

I have installed Atom editor and Atom Beautify package on Ubuntu. However, when opening a new file and trying to "Beautify editor contents" with right-click, Atom pops up the following notice:

> Could not find "emacs". The program may not be installed. You can configure Atom Beautify with the absolute path to "emacs" by setting "Executable - Emacs - Path" in the Atom Beautify package settings. Your program is properly installed if running "which emacs" in your Terminal returns an absolute path to the executable.

I try "which emacs" in the Terminal, but nothing returns. Does it mean that Atom Beautify depends on emacs, so to beautify the code in Atom, I should also install emacs?

Could anyone explain how can I configure Atom Beautify with the absolute path to "emacs" by setting "Executable - Emacs - Path" in the Atom Beautify package settings? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message you are seeing is a generic message they will give all when the application cannot find `emacs`.  Ubuntu doesn't come with `emacs` installed by default, so you will have to install it.  Once installed it is in the `/usr/bin` folder and the application should be able to find it.

From a terminal window run:

```
sudo apt install emacs
```